# Stack and Queue with java

Tags: java, stack, queue

I was trying to solve the question below, but i was so unsure of the function of `Q.insert(S.top())`
Below is the question:
Fill the table showing the output of a series of priority queue and stack operations and their effect on an
initially empty priority queue Q of integers and an empty stack S of integers. Make sure to indicate the
orientation of each data structure you display (i.e. front, rear, top, bottom). (10p)

| Operation | Output | Stack S | Queue Q | rear | front |

```
Q.insert(9)

Q.insert(11)

Q.peek()

S.push(8)

Q.insert(S.top())

S.push(Q.remove())

Q.insert(Q.remove())

S.size() == Q.size()
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I get what you are trying to ask, but where is your effort?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the queue *Q* and the stack *S* are empty at the start of this series of operations...

```
S.push(8)
```

puts 1 element on the stack with value '8'

```
S.top()
```

then returns '8'

When calling a function like `Q.insert(<param>)` the parameter does not have to be a constant; it could be a variable or anything that will produce the right type of parameter.

So if you have methods such as

```
public void insert(int n);
public int top(); // returns an int(eger)
```

You can call insert any of these ways

```
int meaning = 42;
Q.insert( 10 );
Q.insert( meaning );
Q.insert( Math.round(3.14) ); // 'round' produces an int
```

so...

```
Q.insert(S.top())
```

inserts the '8' returned from S.top() into the queue.